# Долгая компиляция less

Tags: gulp, less

Не могу понять, почему так долго компилируется `less`. Уже отключил все модули кроме самого `less` и `sourcemap`:

```js
gulp.task("css", () => {
  return gulp.src("./src/css/style.less")
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(less())
    // .pipe(gcmq())
    // .pipe(autoprefixer({
    //     browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
    //     cascade: false
    // }))
    // .pipe(csso({restructure:false}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./build/css"))

});
```

Первая компиляция происходит нормально, но при следующих сохранениях компилирует до 5-6 секунд. Версия `less` – 3.5.0.